# How to disable a decorator on a method, if that method is called in django tests?

Tags: python, django, oop, decorator, django-unittest

I have a function that is like:

```
@dec_func
def a():
    do_something;
```

In my django tests this function is ran in execution. Now i want that whenever the tests run my function `a` should not get decorated `dec_func` but if the function runs in development or production environment, method should be decorated. How to do so.

Comment: Do you control the decorator source code?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes I can override its code.

Comment: You could read the settings or env there and in the test env just return the original function.

Comment: Yeah i did same now. Its working fine.